# quarkus: CORS on REST resources not working with a javax.ws.rs.@Path("/persons")?

Tags: quarkus

#### Scenario - Client

Developing a ReactJS application with http://localhost:3000 and

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/persons')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(jsonData => console.log(jsonData));
```

#### Scenario - Server

to a Quarkus REST Resource WITH javax.ws.rs.@Path annotation

```
@Path("/persons")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class PersonResource ..
```

and **quarkus application properties** contains

```
quarkus.http.cors=true
```

(or similar, more details won't make it better)

#### Error

results in JavaScript console output

'''Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/persons' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.'''

#### astonishing additional information

When not using @Path("/persons") in the fetch, there is no CORS problem (but of course other problems)

#### Environment

Windows10 Professional 64Bit, 64Bit GraalVM CE Java11 20.2, Quarkus 1.8.1, 1.8.3 Final

Answer (score 0):

You need to add more details about your CORS mechanism, here is an example that should work fine with you :

> quarkus.http.cors=true

and the below need to be enabled too:

> quarkus.http.cors.origins=http://localhost:3000
> quarkus.http.cors.headers=accept,origin,authorization,content-type,x-requested-with
> quarkus.http.cors.methods=GET,POST,PUT,OPTIONS

Comment: This is my application.properties now

Comment: **application.properties**quarkus.http.cors=true
> quarkus.http.cors.origins=http://localhost:3000
> quarkus.http.cors.headers=access-control-allow-origin,accept,origin,authorization,content-type,x-requested-with
> quarkus.http.cors.methods=GET,POST,PUT,OPTIONS

Comment: and the JavaScript call with vanilla fetch (whatwg-fetch)

Comment: fetch('http://localhost:8080/persons', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:3000'
        }
    })

Comment: Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/persons' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: This is really a pity because I like quarkus very much - but as long as this does not work, I cannot use it.

Comment: Thank you for your patience and willingness to help!

Comment: The clue seems to be that the access-control-allow-origin header is not valid vor the /person resource.For the root / it seems to work fine.

Comment: SpringBoot shows the same behaviour. things get more exiting every hour...

Answer (score 0):

## Resolution: User Edge, not Chrome.

**SpringBoot** showed the same behaviour, but I know for sure that SpringBoot is working fine. So maybe the rest implementations do not yet support chrome's security settings to the latest notch.

Since I have a workaround now that is good enough I discontinue this research.